# Why does Scipy's Convex Hull algorithm find so many Simplices that share the same point?

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I'm using Scipy's Convex Hull algorithm to find the surface area of a group of points. The points are each an atomic position in a crystal lattice, and together have the shape of a Truncated Octahedron.

I would like to find out which surface planes are most common by calculating each simplexes normal. However, when I get simplex information for my array of points, many of the simplices seem to share the same point. This doesn't seem possible to me without Convex Hull incorrectly selecting the surface, or selecting the same surface multiple times.

Scipy notes that the simplices array contains the indices of the points which make up the simplical facets, so each simplex is defined by three indices from the points in the array. An example of a point being repeated in this array is below:

```
 [...[14689 13913 14003]
 [14689   919   589]
 [14689  1830  1230]
 [14689    13    11]
 [14689   919   918]
 [14689 14086 13833]
 [14689  1230 13833]
 [14689    13   313]
 [14689   589   313]
 [14689  1223    42]
 [14689 13913 14086]
 [14689 14996 13617]
 [14689    20    11]
 [14689 14967 14828]
 [14689 13734 13617]
 [14689   992   918]
 [14689    20    42]
 [14689 14851 14967]
 [14689 14996 14828]
 [14689   992 13734]
 [14689  1223  1830]
 [14689 14675 14003]]
```

The index 14689 is repeated 22 times. Does anyone understand why Scipy is doing this? Or know of any other software which could be better for getting detailed information about the Convex Hull of a group of points? Scipy's implementation is based on Qhull.

Comment: This *could* just be correct. Sometimes convex hulls look like this. Have you verified that your convex hull doesn't really look like this?

Comment: The shape of the points is a Truncated Octahedron with regular spacing as it's a crystal lattice. So looking at it it seems wrong to me for one point to be used so many times! I'm not aware of any visualisation software that would let me look at the simplices, if you know of any I'll definitely take a look. I realise it could just be the way the convex hull is, but it seems so unlikely to me given the shape of it.